ValueError: Invalid parameter activation for estimator KerasRegressor
My code:
#network
from matplotlib import pyplot
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense,Dropout
from keras.metrics import mae
from keras .optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor


# Define the LSTM network architecture
# Define the LSTM network architecture
def create_lstm_model(neurons, optimizer, activation):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=neurons, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1],train_X.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation=activation))
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=optimizer)
    return model

# define the grid search parameters
param_grid = {'neurons': [8, 16, 32, 64, 128],
              'optimizer': ['SGD', 'RMSprop', 'Adam'],
              'activation':['relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid', 'linear','swish']}

model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_lstm_model, epochs=10, batch_size=16, verbose=0)

# Apply grid search
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid,cv=3,refit=False, scoring="neg_mean_absolute_error", n_jobs = -1)
grid_result = grid.fit(train_X, train_y, validation_data=(test_X, test_y))

Error message:
ValueError: Invalid parameter activation for estimator KerasRegressor.
This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the KerasRegressor constructor:
`KerasRegressor(activation=relu)`
Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`

Note
Similar questions got 0 answers:
ValueError: Invalid parameter learning_rate for estimator KerasRegressor
Python (SciKeras): 'ValueError: Invalid parameter dropout_rate for estimator KerasRegressor.'

There's not a lot of detail about what you are doing here, or what you have tried to resolve the problem. Could you edit it and add an introduction prior to showing the code? What are you trying to achieve?

Based on https://gist.github.com/adriangb/1e69beb15c708544c6e06111be9bc83a
I've amended my code as follows and it is working:
#network
from matplotlib import pyplot
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense,Dropout
from keras.metrics import mae
from keras .optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
from keras import backend as k


# Define the LSTM network architecture
# Define the LSTM network architecture
def auto_CreateNeural(
    compile_kwargs,
    neurons1,
    neurons2,
    neurons3, 
    activation,
    optimizer='Adam'
    
):
    k.clear_session()
    regressor = Sequential(
        [
            LSTM(units=neurons1, 
                 input_shape=(train_X.shape[1],train_X.shape[2])
            ),
            Dense(
                units=neurons2,
                activation=activation,
            ),
            Dropout(0.2),
            Dense(
                units=neurons3, 
                activation=activation
            ),
            Dropout(0.2),
            Dense(units=1, activation="linear"),
        ]
    )
    regressor.compile(
        optimizer=compile_kwargs["optimizer"],
        loss=compile_kwargs["loss"],
        metrics=["mse"],
    )
    return regressor

regressor = KerasRegressor(
    model=auto_CreateNeural,
    verbose=0,
    optimizer="adam",
    loss="MeanAbsoluteError",
    neurons1=128,
    neurons2= 100,
    neurons3=50, 
    activation='relu'
)

# define the grid search parameters
param_grid = {'neurons1': [128,32,64],
              'optimizer': ['SGD', 'RMSprop', 'Adam'],
              'activation':['relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid', 'linear','swish']}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=regressor,
    param_grid=param_grid,
    scoring="neg_mean_absolute_error",
    cv=3,
    verbose=3,
    n_jobs=-1,
)
grid_result = grid_search.fit(train_X, train_y, validation_data=(test_X, test_y))


# summarize results
print("Best accuracy of: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_,
                                         grid_result.best_params_))

means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))

